# Can you build a hashtable dynamically from a variable with multiple data rows in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert the below code to a PowerShell function as I will be using it multiple times in other scripts.  I am trying to figure out how I can allow the user to simply pass a SQL Query (a String) to this script that I will turn into a function and have my hash table `$row` define the keys dynamically based on the column headers and then assign the values when multiple rows are returned by my SQL Query variable `$QueryResults`.  Also, I will have two common variables in each hash table, which are "DateTime" and "ServerName" so those will have to be added as well.

```
$endpoint = "myPowerBIEndpoint"

$Query = "
myQueryThatReturnsMultipleRecords
        "

$GetDate = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)

while($true)
{
        if((Get-Date) -gt $GetDate)
        {
            #Only run the below every 5 minutes
            $GetDate = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)

            #Get list of server to iterate through
            $ServerList = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance "" -Database "" -Query "
            EXEC [dbo].[myProc] @MonitorType" -SqlParameters @{MonitorType = "AGHealth"}

        }
        
        $ServerResults = @() # Results from each of the servers will be stored here

        foreach ($Server in $ServerList)
        {

            $QueryResults = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $ServerList.Cname -Database "" -Query $Query

            $DateTime = Get-Date -DisplayHint Datetime -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

            foreach ($object in $QueryResults)
            {
                Write-Host 'Building Payload for' $object.replica_server_name
                $row = @{
                "DateTime" = $DateTime
                "Replica_Server" = $object.replica_server_name
                "Log_Send_Queue_Size_mb" = $object.total_log_send_queue_size_mb
                "Redo_Queue_Size_mb" = $object.total_redo_queue_size_mb
                "Sync_Health" = $object.synchronization_health
                "Is_Primary_Replica" = $object.is_primary_replica
                "AG_Name" = $object.ag_name
                "ServerName" = $Server.Cname
                }
                $ServerResults += $row
            }
        }

    $payload = @{ "rows" = $ServerResults }

    Write-Host 'Invoking Rest Method'
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $payload)

    (ConvertTo-Json $payload)

    sleep 60
}
```

Comment: "allow the user to simply pass a SQL Query" - doesn't `Invoke-DbaQuery` already solve this problem?

Comment: That is not the question.  I need to know how to convert a SQL Query invoked by Invoke-DbaQuery into a hash table.  The above code will do exactly that, but as you can see I am hardcoding my $row hash table keys.  To clarify further, how do I take the results of $QueryResults (which will change) and build my $row hash table similar to how I have it now, but be done dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Invoke-DbaQuery`is somehow a wrapper of `Invoke-SqlCmd`, we can use the schema information stored in the returned PSObject `[DataRow]` for each row. Each one has a `Table` member filled by the command describing the **resulting** schema for the row. In this `[DataTable]Table`  member, we have the `[DataColumnCollection]Columns` which describes each column of the row as `[DataColmun]`. We can then use that to feed a hash with the `ColumnName` member as a key and use the indexed array `Item` of the row for this `ColumnName` as value.

The specific corresponding PowerShell code, we add `DateTime` and `ServerName` distinctively because they are not coming from the `[DataRow]` itself :

```
                $row = @{}
                $object.Table.Columns | %{ $row.Add($_.ColumnName, $object.Item($_.ColumnName) ) }
                $row.Add("DateTime", $DateTime)
                $row.Add("ServerName", $Server.Cname)
```

The resulting script :

```
$GetDate = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)

while($true)
{
        if((Get-Date) -gt $GetDate)
        {
            #Only run the below every 5 minutes
            $GetDate = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)

            #Get list of server to iterate through
            $ServerList = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance "" -Database "" -Query "
            EXEC [dbo].[myProc] @MonitorType" -SqlParameters @{MonitorType = "AGHealth"}

        }
        
        $ServerResults = @() # Results from each of the servers will be stored here

        foreach ($Server in $ServerList)
        {

            $QueryResults = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $ServerList.Cname -Database "" -Query $Query

            $DateTime = Get-Date -DisplayHint Datetime -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

            foreach ($object in $QueryResults)
            {
                Write-Host 'Building Payload for' $object.replica_server_name
                $row = @{}
                $object.Table.Columns | %{ $row.Add($_.ColumnName, $object.Item($_.ColumnName) ) }
                $row.Add("DateTime", $DateTime)
                $row.Add("ServerName", $Server.Cname)
                $ServerResults += $row
            }
        }

    $payload = @{ "rows" = $ServerResults }

    Write-Host 'Invoking Rest Method'
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $payload)

    (ConvertTo-Json $payload)

    sleep 60
}
```

Comment: That works flawlessly.  I almost had the answer, but your method is much simpler to understand and uses less foreach loops.  Thanks!

Comment: @DylanJanszen If it's ok, i'll edit to add some explanations of what we're doing here.

Comment: Absolutely! Go ahead.

Comment: This might require a new post, but can I reliably do the same with the results from 'Invoke-Command' of a powershell cmdlet such as 'Get-WinEvent' assuming it returns an array?  I can access the properties by piping the psobject to 'Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty', but not sure how to access the values.

Comment: You can do the same with cmdlet like `Get-WinEvent`. This one returns `[EventLogConfiguration[]]`, an array of `[EventLogConfiguration]` **objects**.  So you can do `$Logs=@{}; $(Get-WinEvent -ListLog "Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp*" -ComputerName localhost | %{ $Logs.Add($_.LogName, $_.MaximumSizeinBytes) })` for example, and you get an `[Hashtable]` in `$Logs` indexed by _LogName_ with their maximum size as value.

Comment: That part makes sense, but how can I access the the property names (aka column names) and make those my keys and then add the corresponding values dynamically.  I'd like to be able to pass any cmdlet in to my function, invoke-command on that cmdlet for each of my servers and build a hashtable dynamically. Dynamically identifying the column names and making those my keys w/ the corresponding values is where I am stuck.

Comment: Okay so I solved this problem by first converting my psobject to a data table.

Comment: Ok, got it, you can also do that with `$Log=@{}; $(Get-WinEvent -ListLog "Microsoft-Windows-Dhcpv6-Client/Admin"  -ComputerName localhost | %{ $cur=$_; $cur.GetType().Getproperties() | %{ $n=$_.Name; $Log.Add($n, $cur.$n) }})`. (But why do want to transform `[EventLogConfiguration]`into a `[Hashtable]` ?)